# Python AWS lambda - Dockerfile with playwright module

Tags: python-3.x, docker, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, python-module

I created an AWS lambda with Python3.7 and decided to use Docker to deploy my handler.
My project structure look like this:

- project

  - first_lambda

    - first_lambda.py
    - requirements.txt
    - Dockerfile
  - second_lambda

    - second_lambda.py
    - requirements.txt
    - Dockerfile

In AWS console I created first_lambda_function and second_lambda_function
The first one works correctly, the second one instead breaks with this error:

```
   [ERROR] Error: 
================================================================================
"webkit" browser was not found.
Please complete Playwright installation via running
"python -m playwright install"
================================================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/get_contents_list.py", line 17, in lambda_handler
    tiktok_api = TikTokApi.get_instance(custom_verifyFp=verify_fp, use_test_endpoints=True)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TikTokApi/tiktok.py", line 148, in get_instance
    TikTokApi(**kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TikTokApi/tiktok.py", line 58, in __init__
    self.browser = browser(**kwargs)
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TikTokApi/browser.py", line 82, in __init__
    raise e
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/TikTokApi/browser.py", line 79, in __init__
    args=self.args, **self.options
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/sync_api/_generated.py", line 8959, in launch
    firefoxUserPrefs=mapping.to_impl(firefox_user_prefs),
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_sync_base.py", line 103, in _sync
    return task.result()
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/site-packages/playwright/_impl/_browser_type.py", line 78, in launch
    raise not_installed_error(f'"{self.name}" browser was not found.')
```

This module is used in both lambdas, declared in both requirements.txt and I can't figure out why in the second one doesn't get installed.
The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m playwright install

COPY first_lambda.py .

CMD ["first_lambda.lambda_handler"]
```

Dockerfile 2:

```
FROM amazon/aws-lambda-python:3.7

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN python -m playwright install

COPY second_lambda.py .

CMD ["second_lambda.lambda_handler"]
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This `python -m playwright install` doesn't look like an error message to me, given the little informations you gave us about your project and considering the size of `playwright` I would say that your lambda has time out. But again without any more infos impossible to help you more than that

Comment: HI @Mathix420 , I edited my question with the correct error message. The first one I put was meaningless, indeed. By the way, the lambda has 2 minutes before time out and gives this error after a few second. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, so it can be 2 things. Either the second `requirements.txt` is not using same versions of some dependency, and or have conflicts with other dep (need more log to check). Either there is an error during execution of `python -m playwright install` and to check we also need more log.